# Create links in single image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create some links in single image.I know we can do it with area map.i have used [this](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html#) link for help

Please have a look at link.

But now my requirement is to show the selected state as active.Along with this we also want to select multiple state at a time which should we active.

**select state with control key combination is below**

```
click = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get clicked area element.
                var i = e.srcElement || e.target;

                /**
                * Turn on/off alwaysOn option (boolean, false by default).
                * Indicates whether to always show the hilighted areas.
                */
                i.alwaysOn = !i.alwaysOn;


                if (window.event) {
                    key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
                    if (window.event.ctrlKey)
                        isCtrl = true;
                    else
                        isCtrl = false;
                }
                else {
                    key = e.which;     //firefox
                    if (e.ctrlKey)
                        isCtrl = true;
                    else
                        isCtrl = false;
                }


                // Apply changes.
                if (isCtrl == true) {
                    i.alwaysOn = true;
                    $(i).data('maphilight', i).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
                }
                else {
                    i.alwaysOn = false;
                    $(img).hasClass('maphilighted').each(function() {

                        $(this).data('maphilight', i).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
                      /* here i want remove all selected (highlighted) state */
                    });
                }

            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code allows you to select multiple states on the map.

```
$('map').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get clicked area element.
    // Works in IE, FF, Chrome.
    var i = e.srcElement || e.target;

    /**
      * Turn on/off alwaysOn option (boolean, false by default).
      * Indicates whether to always show the hilighted areas.
      */
    i.alwaysOn = !i.alwaysOn;

    // Apply changes.
    $(i).data('maphilight', i).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    // Explicitly adding a class to the element.
    $(i).addClass('maphilighted');
});
```

[Read about how to toggle highlighting](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html).

---

**Update on un-highlighting.**

You can't call function `each` after `hasClass`, because the latter returns boolean expression, **not** a list of objects.

Here's working code for un-highlighting:

```
if (!isCtrl) {
    i.alwaysOn = false;
    $('area').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('maphilighted')) {
            $(this).data('maphilight', i).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 2.**

```
if (isCtrl) {
    i.alwaysOn = true;
    $(i).data('maphilight', i).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    $(i).addClass('maphilighted');
} else {
    el = $(i.parentNode).children().each(function() {
        this.alwaysOn = false;
        if ($(this).hasClass('maphilighted')) {
            $(this).data('maphilight', this).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
            $(this).removeClass('maphilighted');
        }
    });

    i.alwaysOn = true;
    $(i).data('maphilight', i).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    $(i).addClass('maphilighted');
}
```

Comment: Hello Bar thanks for your response..i have added this code in my js file but getting "Error: window.event undefined" in error console. Please let me know where i am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Amit, I've corrected event handling. Try this `var i = e.srcElement || e.target;` instead of `window.event`.

Comment: Thanks a lots buddy.That's what i want.its working perfectly.Thanks again.

Comment: hi bar please check above...  i have added some further points.. I am trying to select state with control button selection.i have done with select multiple state with control key combination but i facing problem in removing each highlighted state without control selection.Its mean if i unhold the control key and select any state then all selected state highlight should be remove.please let me know if u need any clarification.thanks in advance.

Comment: @Amit What is `img`? I think, you should use `'area'` instead. And why do you select elements with a `maphilighted` class? I don't see you're adding this class explicitly. Try add this class using `$(i).addClass('maphilighted');` See updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lots buddy... Ur code was really very helpful for us.Thanks :)

Comment: And also Bar, if i want to select single state at first time and then multiple with control combination ?? Just like desktop file selection functionality.Thats means if i select state first time then it should be selected and for selecting multiple state control key should be pressed.All is working till here but when i again un hold key and select some another state then that single state should be selected and all others should be unhilighted , that's what not working. Sorry for botheration you.Please do reply whenever u have time.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a image map with active state, this should help you with what you want to do

http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/methodology/revisiting-the-html-image-map/

Comment: Hey nokiko ,, thanks for your kind reply. but i don't want use images for creating active state.I want to do it with Jquery and CSS only. Is their other way to do like this.Thanks

Comment: don't know how you would go about this without extra images that do the highlight. Maybe you could try and put the image in using a canvas tag and then draw poly lines over it.